# symfony2 acl groups

Tags: symfony, acl, usergroups

Generally I have the following business model:

There're users and groups. Each user belongs to only one group and amount of groups is not determined beforehead (as well as amount of users for most sites).
Also there're several different busyness objects, which may belong to user.

Groups are not separate objects, which should be controlled by ACL themselves, but they should affect how other entities should be controlled much like unix groups.

There're 3 basic roles: SUPERADMIN, ADMIN and USER.

- SUPERADMIN is able to do anything with any entity.
- USER is generally able to read/write own entities (including him/her-self) and read
  entitites from his/her group.
- ADMIN should have full control of
  entities within his group, but not from other groups. I don't
  understand how to apply ACL inheritance here (and whether this could
  be applied at all).

Also I'm interested in, how denying access could be applied in ACL. Like user have read/write access to all his fields except login. User should only read his login.
I.e. it is logical to provide read/write access to his own profile, but deny write to login, rather than defining read/write access to all his fields (except login) directly.

Comment: Ok, I've solved it w/o using ACL, but with possibility of ACL integration: I registered my own voter service.

Comment: @krilloid - I have the same question as you. Would you be able to share your voter service code? It would be much appreciated. thanks

Comment: kirilloid If you found a suitable design it would be a good idea to post it here, answering your own question. Like @Flukey I would appreciate it as I am approaching to a similar task. Thanks.

Comment: @Flukey I've posted my code in answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here it is. Code isn't perfect at all, but it's better, than nothing.

Voter service.

```
<?php
namespace Acme\AcmeBundle\Services\Security;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\VoterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Acl\Domain\ObjectIdentity;

class GroupedConcernVoter implements VoterInterface {

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {   
        $this->container = $container;
        $rc = $this->container->getParameter('grouped_concern_voter.config');
        // some config normalization performed
        $this->rightsConfig = $rc;
    }   

    // even though supportsAttribute and supportsClass methods are required by interface,
    // services that I saw, leaves them empty and do not use them

    public function supportsAttribute($attribute)
    {   
        return in_array($attribute, array('OWNER', 'MASTER', 'OPERATOR', 'VIEW', 'EDIT', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'UNDELETE', 'DEPLOY'))
            // hacky way to support per-attribute edit and even view rights.
            or preg_match("/^(EDIT|VIEW)(_[A-Z]+)+$/", $attribute);
    }           

    public function supportsClass($object)
    {   
        $object = $object instanceof ObjectIdentity ? $object->getType() : $object;
        // all our business object, which should be manageable by that code have common basic class.
        // Actually it is a decorator over Propel objects with some php magic... nevermind.
        // If one wants similar solution, interface like IOwnableByUserAndGroup with
        // getUserId and getGroupId methods may be defined and used
        return is_subclass_of($object, "Acme\\AcmeBundle\\CommonBusinessObject");
    }       

    function vote(TokenInterface $token, $object, array $attributes)
    {   

        if (!$this->supportsClass($object)) {
            return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;
        }
        if ($object instanceof ObjectIdentity) $object = $object->getType();

        if (is_string($object)) {
            $scope = 'own';
            $entity = $object;
        } else {
            if ($object->getUserId() == $this->getUser()->getId()) {
                $scope = 'own';
            } else if ($object->getGroupId() == $this->getUser()->getGroupId()) {
                $scope = 'group';
            } else {
                $scope = 'others';
            }
            $entity = get_class($object);
        }

        $user = $token->getUser();
        $roles = $user->getRoles();
        $role = empty($roles) ? 'ROLE_USER' : $roles[0];

        $rights = $this->getRightsFor($role, $scope, $entity);
        if ($rights === null) return self::ACCESS_ABSTAIN;

        // some complicated logic for checking rights...
        foreach ($attributes as $attr) {
            $a = $attr;
            $field = '';
            if (preg_match("/^(EDIT|VIEW)((?:_[A-Z]+)+)$/", $attr, $m)) list(, $a, $field) = $m;
            if (!array_key_exists($a, $rights)) return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
            if ($rights[$a]) {
                if ($rights[$a] === true
                or  $field === '')
                    return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }
            if (is_array($rights[$a])) {
                if ($field == '') return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
                $rfield = ltrim(strtolower($field), '_');
                if (in_array($rfield, $rights[$a])) return self::ACCESS_GRANTED;
            }

            return self::ACCESS_DENIED;
        }
    }

    private function getRightsFor($role, $scope, $entity)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($entity, $this->rightsConfig)) {
            $rc = $this->rightsConfig[$entity];
        } else {
            $rc = $this->rightsConfig['global'];
        }
        $rc = $rc[$role][$scope];
        $ret = array();
        foreach($rc as $k => $v) {
            if (is_numeric($k)) $ret[$v] = true;
            else $ret[$k] = $v;
        }
        // hacky way to emulate cumulative rights like in ACL
        if (isset($ret['OWNER'])) $ret['MASTER'] = true;
        if (isset($ret['MASTER'])) $ret['OPERATOR'] = true;
        if (isset($ret['OPERATOR']))
            foreach(array('VIEW', 'EDIT', 'CREATE', 'DELETE', 'UNDELETE') as $r) $ret[$r] = true;
        return $ret;
    }

    private function getUser() {
        if (empty($this->user)) {
            // Not sure, how this shortcut works. This is a service (?) returning current authorized user.
            $this->user = $this->container->get('acme.user.shortcut');
        }
        return $this->user;
    }

}
```

And config... actually, it is implementation-specific and its structure is completely arbitrary.

```
grouped_concern_voter.config:
    global:
        ROLE_SUPERADMIN:
            own: [MASTER]
            group: [MASTER]
            others: [MASTER]
        ROLE_ADMIN:
            own: [MASTER]
            group: [MASTER]
            others: []
        ROLE_USER:
            own: [VIEW, EDIT, CREATE]
            group: [VIEW]
            others: []
    "Acme\\AcmeBundle\\User":
        # rights for ROLE_SUPERADMIN are derived from 'global'
        ROLE_ADMIN:
            own:
                VIEW: [login, email, real_name, properties, group_id]
                EDIT: [login, password, email, real_name, properties]
                CREATE: true
            group:
                VIEW: [login, email, real_name, properties]
                EDIT: [login, password, email, real_name, properties]
            # rights for ROLE_ADMIN/others are derived from 'global'
        ROLE_USER:
            own:
                VIEW: [login, password, email, real_name, properties]
                EDIT: [password, email, real_name, properties]
            group: []
            # rights for ROLE_USER/others are derived from 'global'
    "Acme\\AcmeBundle\\Cake":
        # most rights are derived from global here.
        ROLE_ADMIN:
            others: [VIEW]
        ROLE_USER:
            own: [VIEW]
            others: [VIEW]
```

And finally usage example. Somewhere in controller:

```
$cake = Acme\AcmeBundle\CakeFactory->produce('strawberry', '1.3kg');
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
if ($securityContext->isGranted('EAT', $cake)) {
    die ("The cake is a lie");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when creating a group, create role ROLE_GROUP_(group id), promote group with this role, and grant permissions with rolesecurityidentity

Comment: I've thought about it, but there're different roles within group. Also I should update all roles if user changes group.

Comment: @kirilloid      
you can always create ROLE_GROUP_A_(group id), ROLE_GROUP_B_(group id), and so on, and i dont really understand, what do you mean by "update all roles if user changes group"(?) when user changes group it have automatically roles from this new group, and dont have any of roles of the previous one

Comment: Changing "the rules of the game" require update bunch of ACL records. The other day I decide, there's a new right TASTE and anybody may taste any cake. In case of groups as roles I should write some new code and do a DB migration updating current ACL. Inb case of my config I should only update one line in config:
`ROLE_USER: others: [TASTE]`